# GRUB can't find windows ESP

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I have 2 ESP, which may be the problem but I think it's possible to fix as I can manually boot using GRUB SET. Anyway this is my setup. Pls ignore certain possible typo as I'm retyping on other machine:

```
fdisk -l

/dev/sda1    Windows recovery
/dev/sda2    EFI system
/dev/sda3    Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5    Windows recovery
/dev/sda6    EFI System (linux)
/dev/sda7    Linux fs
```

inside linux:

```
# grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
4C77-A2D0
# grub-probe --target=hints_string /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
--hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2
```

so in GRUB entry I use:

```
insmod part-gpt
insmod fat
insmod search_fs_uuid
insmod chain
search --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2 4C77-A2D0
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

This causes following error when trying to boot into windows:

```
error: unspecified search type
error: file '/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found.
```

So I go in GRUB command line:

```
grub> set
...
cmdpath=(hd1,gpt6)/EFI/grub
...
grub> search.fs_uuid 4C77-A2D0
 hd1,gpt2
```

I'm in hd1 instead of hd0 and grub could find by UUID. I tried modifying my menuentry hintstrings to search `hd1,gpt2` instead but still same error. Also I tried `drivemap -s hd1`. It still can't find the partition.

My question is why does GRUB show different hd#. 
And how do I get it to locate the partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to `# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` after editing `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`......

Comment: It would be useful to *accept* this answer to mark the question as "answered".